# How to access 12c report metadata?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, obiee, bi-publisher

I am looking for a method (or even better a DW table) that contains report properties such as Name, Description, Type, Location, etc.

I have looked through many tables but can not find this information. I am working to build out a web portal that includes hyperlinks for all reports on the server.

Here is an example of report properties I am looking for-

[image: OBIEE report properties]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the definitions you're looking for are not stored at the database level, which is super lame, but that's the way it is. They're stored in the RPD file and the web catalog at the OS level.

The webcatalog is located:

- on 10G: OracleBIData/web/catalog/
- on 11G:
  $ORACLE_INSTANCE/bifoundation/OracleBIPresentationServicesComponent/catalog/
- on 12c: $ORACLE_HOME\user_projects\domains\bi\bidata\service_instances\ssi\metadata\content\catalog where ssi is a service instance.

  If you descend into one of those directory structures you'll see files that are named with a bunch of punctuation symbols, plus the name of the report they represent.

[Reference 1](https://gerardnico.com/dat/obiee/obips/webcat)
[Reference 2](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4202112)

Comment: Is this accessible for BI Publisher hosted in Oracle Cloud Fusion? I am looking to get all the report-related objects (Data Model, Report obj.) and the user who created them and date created. I looking in the Administration area but could not find anything that looked applicable.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify the "lame" storage: What the OP is asking for is in the presentation catalog; the RPD has nothing to do with it.
And to clarify even further: Every object stored in the presentation catalog is physically represented by two files on the disk: one file without file extension which represents the object's XML definition. And one file with an .atr extension which contains the object's properties - what the OP is looking for - as well as the object's access permissions.
Ranting's fain, but please be precise ;-)

Comment: "precise" would have been telling OP how to get the information he's looking for out of the .atr file. The point I was making is that the data is not in the database.

Comment: Not really because you're never ever supposed to work directly with the content of the atr files.

Answer (score -1):

For what it's worth, in E-Business Suite, tables start with `XDO_`

Comment: Is this accessible for BI Publisher hosted in Oracle Cloud Fusion? I am looking to get all the report-related objects (Data Model, Report obj.) and the user who created them and date created. I looking in the Administration area but could not find anything that looked applicable.